# How to retrieve row's last modification timestamp in HBase?

Tags: java, hbase

Does each Cell in returned Result object have same timestamp?
Is it save to do something like this?

```
  try (Table table = connectionFactory.getConnection().getTable(TABLE)) {
   try (ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(generateScan(systemId))) {
    for (Result result: scanner) {
     if (result == null) {
      break;
     }
     long ts = result.rawCells()[0].getTimestamp();
     System.out.println("Row last update time: " + ts);
    }
   }
  }
```

Will I obtain time stamp of the last row modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells in Result can have different timestamp. Each cell is a combination of `CF:C:V`, where `CF` is column family, `C` is a column and `V` is a version. Even if you store only 1 version, you can update columns of a cell independently. Cell timestamp is updated when you store something.

For example you have table `user` with `cf:main` and two columns `name` and `age`. If you update both columns in same `Put` they will have same timetamp. If you update only `name` column, timestamps will be different. So generally it depends on your usage pattern.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wasn't sure about.